# How to access text value outside of initialization of Radiobutton

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button, getter, setter

```
fruit_frame = LabelFrame(root, text = "Fruit", padx = 15, pady = 15) fruit_frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

veg_frame = LabelFrame(root, text = "Vegetables", padx = 15, pady = 15) veg_frame.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

meat_frame = LabelFrame(root, text = "Meats", padx = 15, pady = 15) meat_frame.grid(row = 0, column = 2)

reciept_frame = LabelFrame(root, text = "Reciept", padx = 15, pady = 15) reciept_frame.grid(row = 5, column = 1)

FRUITS = [
    ("Mango", 5.99),
    ("Blueberry", 1.99),
    ("Banana", 0.99),
    ("Guava", 6.99)
    ]

VEGIES = [
    ("Beet Root", 2.99),
    ("Kale", 3.99),
    ("Squash", 3.50),
    ("Cauliflower", 4.99)
    ]

MEATS = [
    ("Lamb Chop", 12.99),
    ("Pork Belly", 10.99),
    ("Wings", 4.50),
    ("Steak", 11.99)
    ]

amount = DoubleVar() 
amount.set(23) 
x = 0 
a = x 
b = x 
c = x 
total = x 
y = x 
w = x    

for fruit, price, in FRUITS:
   Radiobutton(fruit_frame, text = fruit, variable = amount, value = price).grid(row = 0 + a, column = 0, columnspan = 3, sticky = W+E)
   a += 1
   item = fruit


 for vegie, price, in VEGIES:
    Radiobutton(veg_frame, text = vegie, variable = amount, value = price).grid(row = 0 + b, column = 1, columnspan = 3, sticky = W+E)
    b += 1
    item = vegie

for meat, price, in MEATS:
    Radiobutton(meat_frame, text = meat, variable = amount, value = price).grid(row = 0 + c, column = 2, columnspan = 3, sticky = W+E)
    c += 1
    item = meat

def clicked(value): 
    global total total += value total_val = "{:.2f}".format(total)

    my_label = Label(root, text = "Total: $" + str(total_val)) 
    my_label.grid(row = 4, column = 1 )

    global y 
    y += 1 
    global fruit 
    global w 

    item_num = Label(reciept_frame, text = str(y) + "). " + item + ": " + str(value)) 
    item_num.grid(row = 5 + w, column = 1) w += 1

addButton = Button(root, text = "Add to Cart", command = lambda: clicked(amount.get())) 
addButton.grid(row = 3, column = 0, columnspan = 3, sticky = W+E)
```

> I am playing around with Tkinter and I was not sure how to go about
> accessing and storing the text value from the Radiobutton
> initialization, for later use.
>
> The purpose of this program is to create an "insta cart". User has the
> option to click the button, add it to the cart. The goal is to give
> the user, the total amount and a receipt of the items they bought.
> Specifically, I want the receipt to read: Receipt:---
> 1.) Mango: 5.99
>
> My issue is that I am unable to access the text, "Mango", given that
> the user clicked on it. Instead of storing the item type as variable,
> I am storing the price. Perhaps, is it possible to have to variables
> in a single Radiobutton?

[image: code output]

Comment: Your code formatting is all messed up, you have multiple statements on the same line. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: you can use `button["text"]` to get the text of a button.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest to have the following changes:

- use `Variable` (which is the base class of `StringVar`, DoubleVar, etc) instead of `DoubleVar`
- assign `value` option of those `Radiobutton` to `(<item>, price)`

Then you can get the name and price of the selected item easily inside `clicked()`:

```py
...
amount = Variable()
amount.set(0)
...
for fruit, price, in FRUITS:
   Radiobutton(fruit_frame, text = fruit, variable = amount, value = (fruit, price)).grid(row = 0 + a, column = 0, columnspan = 3, sticky = W)
   a += 1

for vegie, price, in VEGIES:
    Radiobutton(veg_frame, text = vegie, variable = amount, value = (vegie, price)).grid(row = 0 + b, column = 1, columnspan = 3, sticky = W)
    b += 1

for meat, price, in MEATS:
    Radiobutton(meat_frame, text = meat, variable = amount, value = (meat, price)).grid(row = 0 + c, column = 2, columnspan = 3, sticky = W)
    c += 1

def clicked(selected):
    global total

    item, value = selected

    total += value
    total_val = "{:.2f}".format(total)

    my_label = Label(root, text = "Total: $" + str(total_val))
    my_label.grid(row = 4, column = 1 )

    global y
    y += 1
    global fruit
    global w

    item_num = Label(reciept_frame, text = str(y) + "). " + item + ": " + str(value))
    item_num.grid(row = 5 + w, column = 1, sticky = W)
    w += 1
...
```